# "AADSTS75005: The request is not a valid SAML 2.0 protocol message." when authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync is used to acquire token

Tags: azure, powerbi

I want to get the Azure AD token display PowerBI reports in my application.

Below code  throws an error : AADSTS75005: The request is not a valid SAML 2.0 protocol message.

```
var authenticationResult1 = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsyn(resourceUri, clientID, credential).Result;
```

Other Method which I have used is:

```
TokenCache TC = new TokenCache();
ClientCredential CC = new ClientCredential(clientID, SecretID);        
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext authenticationContext1= 
       new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authorityUri, TC);
AuthenticationResult result3 = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, CC).Result;
```

The above returns the token though, but when used for displaying PowerBI report I get **forbidden** error.

What am I missing?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Please refer to https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-get-azuread-access-token/ , check the `Access token for non-Power BI users (app owns data)` section

Comment: Hi Nan Yu ,
I have tried the same, still I get ": AADSTS75005: The request is not a valid SAML 2.0 protocol message." error.